# Scale div based on viewport height

Tags: html, css, iframe, html5-video, youtube-iframe-api

Scale a div like a video element.

I want to scale a div just like the html5 video tag.

You can see here in my code sample, the video scales as the height of the viewport changes: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/flawless-coconut-mole?path=index.html%3A17%3A99

I want the same effect but with a div. This div will have an iframe inside of it (Youtube Iframe). I can get the iframe to maintain the 16:9 aspect ration, but I can't get its container to change its height and thus scale its children with it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `script` tag should be in the `head` tag or just after the `body` tag , and the best approach is to write you `JavaScript` logic just after you body tag (To speed up the loading of your web page ).
like that :

you can wrap you iframe tag with a div : 
PS: you need to remove the default height and width attributes

```
<div class="embed">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4VIy9lF_EHg" allowfullscreen </iframe>
</div>
```

and use `CSS` like that:

```
<style>
    .embed {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-top: 56.25%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .embed iframe {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

For the final result :

```css
.embed {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.embed iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Hello!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
  </head>  
  <body>
<div class="embed">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4VIy9lF_EHg" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

  </body>
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The script tag was a default added by Glitch :) I'm not using it.

Your solution is maintaining the aspect ratio, which I can do.

I want the video's container (a separate div wrapper) to change height. So something like:

`
<div class="container">
   <div class="embed">
       <iframe />
   </div>
`
</div>

So I want the container class to change height which will make its children scale to the given height/width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vh` unit in your CSS. Here's an example.

```js
var sizeElement = document.getElementById('window-size');
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight
sizeElement.innerText = `Window size: ${windowWidth} x ${windowHeight}`;
var iframeElement = document.getElementById('iframe-size');
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var iframeWidth = iframe.clientWidth;
var iframeHeight = iframe.clientHeight;
iframeElement.innerText = `iframe size: ${iframeWidth} x ${iframeHeight}`;
var totalSizeElement = document.getElementById('total-size');
totalSizeElement.innerText = `iframe width is ${Math.round(iframeWidth * 100 / windowWidth)}% of window width. iframe height is ${Math.round(iframeHeight * 100 / windowHeight)}% of window height.`;
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  /* Makes sure the iframe is visible */
  height: 9vh;
  width: 16vh;
  /* Maintain aspect ratio */
}

iframe {
  /* iframe takes up entire container */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <iframe></iframe>
<div>
<p id="window-size"></p>
<p id="iframe-size"></p>
<p id="total-size"></p>
```

If you click 'full page' and resize your browser, the `<iframe>` will be sized proportionally.

`vh` and `vw` are units respective to the viewport height and width, respectively. 1 `vh` is equivalent to 1/100 of the viewport height. You can use `max-width` and `min-width`, as well as their height counterparts, to limit how large and small the `<iframe>` can get.